# Task Module of teams not taking the theme background color

Tags: microsoft-teams

Task module body is not taking the teams theme background color .it taking the white color only tried with

#embed-container iframe {

```
        body {

            background-color: inherit !important;
   }
```

}

still not working

Answer (score 0):

Because your code is running inside a frame, the entire contents of your page are explicitly up to you to handle. In addition, if Teams decided to change it's colour, it might not be a combination that worked for your app, so you would be taking a dangerous dependency. Instead, Teams provides a Context object that you can use, to detect the theme type (light,dark, high contrast) **and** any change to the theme while your code is running (e.g. in a tab). See more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/access-teams-context

You might anyway want to look at the Teams UI Component templates though, that include out of box styles etc.: https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-ui-component-library

Comment: I have tried to implement the theme through in the task module, but its not affecting the theme concept in the task module in the developer tool I have noticed that in the body of the page its setting the background color as white. but i didn't add any style for body

Comment: How did you implement the theme for the taskModule? You need to add the theme for the page you display in the task module. Did yo check the sample code provided by @hilton?